# Binding to auxiliary Xaml files located within the immediate namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

The application I'm working on entails a WinUI3 Packaged project which will generate a line grid which contains vertical/horizontal lines overlayed perpendicularly by Line markup (generated by GoogleSheets).  I have two xaml files, one for each of vertical/horizontal xaml code.  I would like to bind both files into MainWindow.xaml to get the grid going on a grid panel for the app.  I need some ideas on how to get the xaml files incorporated into the MainWindow.xaml code for presentation.  I've tried searching for some info but haven't found anything pertinent enough as of yet.  Any ideas? (thanks in advance)

I've tried the following so far:

```
MainWindow.xaml:
<Grid>
    Blank -- waiting for some ideas...
</Grid>


V_Grid.xaml:
<Line x:Name="ln1" X1="0" X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="1500" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
<Line x:Name="ln2" X1="10" X2="10" Y1="0" Y2="1500" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
<Line x:Name="ln3" X1="20" X2="20" Y1="0" Y2="1500" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
<Line x:Name="ln4" X1="30" X2="30" Y1="0" Y2="1500" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
<Line x:Name="ln5" X1="40" X2="40" Y1="0" Y2="1500" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
etc...

H_Grid.xaml:
<Line x:Name="ln1" Y1="0" Y2="0" X1="0" X2="2000" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
<Line x:Name="ln2" Y1="10" Y2="10" X1="0" X2="2000" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
<Line x:Name="ln3" Y1="20" Y2="20" X1="0" X2="2000" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
<Line x:Name="ln4" Y1="30" Y2="30" X1="0" X2="2000" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
<Line x:Name="ln5" Y1="40" Y2="40" X1="0" X2="2000" Stroke="#1f1f1f" StrokeThickness=".3" />
etc...
```

I've tried a couple of ideas which were to no avail.

I tried the following:

```
Within Main.xaml:
<Page x:Name="V_Grid" Resources="V_Grid.xaml"></Page>


Within App.xaml:
<ResourceDictionary>
    
    <Page x:Name="V_Grid" x:Key="V_Grid.xaml"></Page>
    
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    
</ResourceDictionary>

(none of these work...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you might want to try the `XamlReader` for this.

For example:

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        Click="LoadXamlButton_Click"
        Content="Load XAML" />
    <Frame
        x:Name="DynamicFrame"
        Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
private async void LoadXamlButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string loadedXamlText = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("V_Grid.xaml");

    if (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader.Load(loadedXamlText) is FrameworkElement dynamicElement)
    {
        this.DynamicFrame.Content = dynamicElement;
    }
}
```

The file that will be loaded dynamically, should have at least the namespaces required. In this case:

**V_Grid.xaml**

```xml
<Grid
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Line
        x:Name="ln1"
        Stroke="Red"
        StrokeThickness=".3"
        X1="0"
        X2="0"
        Y1="0"
        Y2="1500" />
    <Line
        x:Name="ln2"
        Stroke="Green"
        StrokeThickness=".3"
        X1="10"
        X2="10"
        Y1="0"
        Y2="1500" />
    <Line
        x:Name="ln3"
        Stroke="Blue"
        StrokeThickness=".3"
        X1="20"
        X2="20"
        Y1="0"
        Y2="1500" />
    <Line
        x:Name="ln4"
        Stroke="#1f1f1f"
        StrokeThickness=".3"
        X1="30"
        X2="30"
        Y1="0"
        Y2="1500" />
    <Line
        x:Name="ln5"
        Stroke="#1f1f1f"
        StrokeThickness=".3"
        X1="40"
        X2="40"
        Y1="0"
        Y2="1500" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have a bit more advanced sample in my repo [here](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/DynamicWinUI3SampleApp).

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the information.  I tried the code you suggested and received the following error message: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Models.ColorPickerFlyout.xaml'.'  Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using a button element as mentioned above to simplify to no avail.  Here is the message I received when trying the same method using a frame "f" as the 'DynamicFrame' for the loaded content: XLS0432 "The property 'ColorPickerFlyout' was not found in type MainWindow."

Comment: Can you try passing the full path of ColorPickerFlyout.xaml?

Comment: Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rZsIajf8h8) of mine to see it in action.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the link.  I think that covers it.  I'll have to take my time watching the video to get the method down, but I think that'll get it working.  I think we can close this issue out. :)